# Using absorbance to find amount of a substance in a sample

Tags: experimental-chemistry, spectrophotometry

If you use absorbance to find the amount of one substance that a sample contains, and do three determinations, should you just average the three values and use that? Or just talk about them individually?

Comment: Usually, I would average the values. That is, unless one is much off. Then, I would repeat the measurements and ask myself what went wrong. Is the compound air-sensitive? Is one of the cuvettes contaminated inside? Did I clean the outside of the cuvette properly?

Comment: Alright. That's what I thought, but always best to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! Btw, welcome to Chemistry.SE! If you don't mind the hint, I suggest that you turn your unregistered, cookie-based account into a registered, login-based account. Less hassle, more fun. Have a look at [Why register](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) for details.